# Compound components pattern with Typescript and React Memo

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I work with compound components and hence assign child components to the parent component itself. It usually looks something like this:

```
interface ParentComposition {
    Child: typeof SearchCardChild;
}

interface SearchCardProps {}

export const SearchCard: React.FC<SearchCardProps> & ParentComposition = ({}) => {
        return ...;
};

const SearchCardChild: React.FC = () => {
    return ...
}

SearchCard.Child = SearchCardChild;
```

I'm trying to apply the same pattern to a parent using `React.memo`, but I keep getting the following error:

> Property 'Child' is missing in type 'NamedExoticComponent' but required in type 'ParentComposition'.

```
interface ParentComposition {
    Child: typeof SearchCardChild;
}

interface SearchCardProps {}

export const SearchCard: NamedExoticComponent<SearchCardProps> & ParentComposition = React.memo(({}) => {
        return ...;
});

const SearchCardChild: React.FC = () => {
    return ...
}

SearchCard.Child = SearchCardChild;
```

How can I do so?

Comment: You added the Child property after initializing the variable, and that caused an error. But I'm not sure why it works fine in the first case. You can simply make the Child property optional with the Child?: typeof SearchCardChild;

Comment: Yes making it optional will solve this exact error, but trying to use `<SearchCard.Child />` will then return `JSX element type 'SearchCard.Child' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The composition of components must be after memoization, otherwise property .displayName in BaseForm will cause an error

```
interface IFormProps extends HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> {}

interface MemoizedFormCompose {
  Item: typeof Item;
}

const BaseForm: FC<IFormProps> = ({ children, className, ...props }) => (
  <div {...props}>
    {children}
  </div>
);

const MemoizedForm = React.memo(BaseForm) as NamedExoticComponent<IFormProps> & MemoizedFormCompose;

MemoizedForm.Item = Item;

export const Form = MemoizedForm;
```